# MAX(user_id) not working

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the last insert id from table, I am using `MAX(user_id)`,but its not working (column `user_id` is an auto_increment field) here is my code

`class.php`

```
<?php

class Chat extends Core 
{
   public function addUser($email) {
        $this->query("INSERT INTO `users`(`username`) VALUES ('" . $this->db->real_escape_string($email) . "') ");
        $q = "select MAX(user_id) from `users`";
        $result = mysql_query($q);
        $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    }
}

}

?>
```

when I am running this query I got an warning message like this

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

here is my core.php

```
<?php
class Core {
   protected $db,$result;
   private $rows;
   public function __construct() {
    $this->db=new mysqli('localhost','root','','site');
   }
   public function query($sql)
   {
    $this->result=  $this->db->query($sql);
}
public function rows(){
    for($x=1;$x<=$this->db->affected_rows;$x++)
    {
        $this->rows[]=  $this->result->fetch_assoc();
    }
    return $this->rows;
   }
}

?>
```

can anybody help me.
thanks.

Comment: why not using `$this->query($q)`?

Comment: try `mysql_query($q)or die(mysql_error());` i am sure that will give you error.

Comment: That query will return the last user created by anyone, not necessarily the one you've just created.

Comment: 'no database selected'

Comment: @user2214797 - You're obviously mixing at least two database libraries.

Comment: @user2214797 - well then select a database. As you insist in using the old stuff this would help http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

Comment: @EdHeal It's not so much insisting on using the old stuff as it is not knowing how to properly get the last inserted id using the given library :)

Comment: @Jack - I was using the comment 'no database selected' - hence doing a select database in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using `mysqli` underneath, so this would do what you want:

```
public function addUser($email) 
{
    $this->query("INSERT INTO `users`(`username`) ...");
    $userid = $this->db->insert_id;
    // ... etc ...
}
```

Because `mysqli::$insert_id` is session based, you avoid race conditions that causes the wrong identifier to be passed around.

See also: [`mysqli::$insert_id`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Answer (score 2):

are you trying to get the last inserted id

then use

```
$last_user_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

**Suggestion**

better use ci db function

```
  public function addUser($email) {
    $userData = NULL;
    $result = $this->db->insert('users', array('users' => $email));
    if ($result == TRUE) {
      $user_id = $this->db->insert_id();
      $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('user_id' => $user_id));
      $userData = $query->row_array();
    }
    return $userData;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below function it will fulfill your requirement.

```
 mysql_insert_id()
```

Answer (score 0):

use below one to get last id:

```
mysql_insert_id();
```

AS Mysql function are deprecated you can use

```
mysqli_insert_id()
PDO::lastInsertId()
```